# How can I add Vulkan to a cross platform CMake project?

Tags: c++, cmake, repository, cross-platform, vulkan

In order to make a CMake project as simple and as portable as it can get I have consider to add the "whole" repositories of the libraries I need to the project.
The project structure is as follows:

```
MyProject/
└──CMakeLists.txt
└──src/
    └──MyProject/
        └── *.h & *.cpp
        └── CMakeLists.txt
└──ThirdParty/
    └──Vulkan-Hpp/
        └──(Vulkan Files)
    └──glfw/
        └──(glfw Files)
    └──SFML/
        └──(SFML Files)
```

All the third party directories are the git submodules of the following repositories:
https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Hpp

https://github.com/SFML/SFML

https://github.com/glfw/glfw

Summarizing everything up, I'm having trouble integrating the vulkan and sfml libraries to the project.

MyProject/CMakeLists.txt is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8 FATAL_ERROR)

project ("MyProject")

set (MyProject_VERSION_MAJOR 0)
set (MyProject_VERSION_MINOR 2)
set (MyProject_VERSION_PATCH 1)

set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

# Include sub-projects.
add_subdirectory ("src/MyProject")
add_subdirectory ("ThirdParty/glfw")
add_subdirectory ("ThirdParty/SFML")
add_subdirectory ("ThirdParty/Vulkan-Hpp")
```

MyProject/src/MyProject/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8 FATAL_ERROR)

project ("MyProject")
find_package(Vulkan REQUIRED FATAL_ERROR) # error
find_package(SFML REQUIRED network audio) # error
find_package(glfw REQUIRED FATAL_ERROR) # error

# Add source to this project's executable.
add_executable (MyProject "MyProject.cpp")

target_include_directories (MyProject 
    PUBLIC ${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    PUBLIC ${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR}
    PUBLIC ${VULKAN_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

target_link_libraries (MyProject glfw)
target_link_libraries (MyProject ${VULKAN_LIB_LIST})
target_link_libraries (MyProject ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
```

How can I tweak CMake in order to use the third party libraries at my main project?
Is the project structure incorrect?

Comment: Note that `FATAL_ERROR` is not a valid argument to `find_package`. I suspect you also want to pass `COMPONENTS` before `network audio` for the `SFML` search.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your `find_package(Vulkan REQUIRED FATAL_ERROR)` line is failing, you need to make sure the Vulkan SDK is properly installed, i.e. that you have a VULKAN_SDK environment variable that points to the correct location.

Additionally, do not embed the `KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Hpp` repository.  This repository is for building the Vulkan C++ bindings, but shouldn't be used directly.  Instead you should be using the vulkan.hpp header that is bundled with your installation of the Vulkan SDK.  Otherwise when people try to build your project and have a different version of the Vulkan SDK installed than is referred to by your embedded `KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Hpp`

More generally, you are using `find_package` and then later you're using `add_subdirectory` to try to incorporate these external projects.  That's not how it works.  `find_package` will look for a pre-existing binary of the package, while `add_subdirectory` isn't designed to just swallow entire existing external CMake projects.

If you want to have your project build these others from source you should investigate the use of CMake's [external project functionality](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html).  However, you'll probably find this to be more of a burden than it's worth.  Alternatively, install vcpkg for your target platform, and use vcpkg to build and install glfw and sfml, then tell CMake to use the vcpkg dependencies (see the vcpkg docs on how to pass the CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE to your cmake configure line.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but some things need improvements. The reason to embeed Vulkan-Hpp is so that the development environment needs just a vulkan compatible driver (in other words, the user doesn't have to install vulkan). Can I manage this by means of adding Vulkan-Headers and Vulkan-Loader?

Comment: On Windows and Linux the Vulkan loader is supposed to be installed as part of driver installation, or by the distro as a dependency of the driver. So if your users have a Vulkan driver, they should have the loader -- you shouldn't need to build or install it. You just need the header file that defines your interface to the loader, which is in Vulkan-Headers.

Comment: "so that the development environment needs just a vulkan compatible driver"  That's not going to happen.  The development environment needs the Vulkan SDK.  What you're suggesting sounds akin to basically re-creating the Vulkan SDK as an embedded Git repository.

Comment: Please note that FATAL_ERROR is not a valid argument for find_package, don't use it. For more info see: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/23849